# How to configure Micronaut 4.x to accept application.yml file instead of application.properties file?

Tags: micronaut

I am using Micronaut 4.3.2, and it doesn't seem to be able to read application.yml file as default, only application.properties. Is there a setting somewhere to enable that?

Doesn't seems like anyone else is running into that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add YAML support to your build. In Micronaut 4, Snakeyaml is an optional dependency.

```kotlin
runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
```